# Visualizing data from database as line chart in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I have a really simple request: I have a table that holds a users weight for a specific day (so two columns: kilograms and day). I now want to show this as a line chart to show a user's weight loss over time (x-Axis = day, y-Axis = kilograms).

I installed Chartkick and it renders a chart but it I really don't know how to get these value to the line chart.

Is Chartkick the right option for this purpose? And if yes, how should my code look like?

**weight.rb**

```
class Weight < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :day, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id,
    message: "You already stored a weight today. Go back and edit if necessary." }
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  after_create :create_profile

  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :weights, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: What's your table called? And how are you connecting it to the user table?

Comment: I updated this info in my post above. My table is called "Weights".

Answer (score 1):

Chartkick will do exactly what you want.

For the particular chart.

```
<%= line_chart User.weight_measurements.group_by(day).average(:weight)
```

In this case I'm assuming that your day is not a date. Otherwise you might want to use [groupdate](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) by the same author.

```
<%= line_chart User.weight_measurements.group_by_day(day).average(:weight)
```

There's probably a cleaner way to do it but that should work

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to this.

Chartkicks documentation says:

> Times can be a time, a timestamp, or a string (strings are parsed)
>
> ```
> <%= line_chart({20.day.ago => 5, 1368174456 => 4, "2013-05-07 00:00:00 UTC" => 7}) %>
> ```

So all I did is creating a hash from my Weights table in the suggested format...

**weights_controller.rb**

```
@result = {}
    Weight.where(:user_id => current_user.id).each do |weight|
      @result[weight.day] = weight.kilograms
    end
```

...and used this in the line chart:

```
<%= line_chart(@result, min: nil) %>
```